# C# Accessing values of a derived class in an array of the base class

Tags: c#, arrays, class, radix, derived

This is not exactly what I am working with but I hope it makes a clear example:

```
public abstract class Shape
{
     public int Area;
     public int Perimeter;
     public class Polygon : Shape
     {
         public int Sides;
         public Polygon(int a, int p, int s){
             Area = a;
             Perimeter = p;
             Sides = s;
         }
     }
     public class Circle : Shape
     {
         public int Radius;
         public Circle(int r){
              Area = 3.14*r*r;
              Perimeter = 6.28*r;
              Radius = r;
         }
     }
}
```

In the main function I would have something like this:

```
Shape[] ThisArray = new Shape[5];
ThisArray[0] = new Shape.Circle(5);
ThisArray[1] = new Shape.Polygon(25,20,4);
```

My problem is that when I deal with ThisArray, I can't access values other than Area and Perimeter. **For example:**

```
if (ThisArray[0].Area > 10)
   //This statement will be executed

if (ThisArray[1].Sides == 4)
   //This will not compile
```

**How can I access Sides from ThisArray[1]?** I could access it if I did something like
`Shape.Polygon RandomSquare = new Shape.Polygon(25,20,4)` but not if it is in an array of shapes.

If I recall correctly this could be accomplished in C++ by doing something like
 `Polygon->ThisArray[1].Sides` (I forget what this is called) but I do not know how do this in C#

If I can't do what I am trying to do, how can I circumvent this problem?

Thank you for reading through what I intended to be short, any help is appreciated.

Comment: What you should actually do it reconsider your design, one in which you keep an array of shapes but expect specific Polygon behavior. Also putting the derived classes inside the base class is not idiomatic C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use casting:

```
(ThisArray[1] as Shape.Polygon).Sides
```

Note that you should make sure the underlying object instance actually IS a Polygon, otherwise this will raise an exception. You can do this by using something like:

```
if(ThisArray[1] is Shape.Polygon){
    (ThisArray[1] as Shape.Polygon).Sides
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, I just did not know what to call what I was looking for or the format used in C#. Although you would have to say Shape.Polygon instead of just Polygon.

Comment: You're right, since it's an inner class. Edited. PS: remember to accept this answer if you think it's the correct one ;)